# How can I solve this integral analytically or numerically

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Hi I have an integral to do

$$\nu =\int_{0}^{P(r)} \,\frac{dP}{P+\beta\rho(P)}$$

here I calculated

$$\rho = 0.003 P^{\frac{2}{4}}+ 0.002P^{\frac{2.5}{4}}+0.0019P^{\frac{3}{4}}$$

My question can this integral be solved anyhow?
I tried it in wolfram but it failed, can anyone give me the command in mathematica 10 to solve the integral part only ? I will later put the limits.

reagrds

Comment: 9 times it of 10 if wolfram can not find it neither can the populous. That being said I would be happy to see a solution analytically..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** By the change of variable $$P=x^8, \qquad dP=8x^7dx$$ you readily obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\nu &=\int_{0}^{P(r)} \,\frac{dP}{P+\beta\rho(P)}\\\\
&=8 \int_{0}^{\sqrt[8]{P(r)}} \,\frac{x^7}{x^8+\beta \left(0.0019x^6+0.002x^5+0.003x^4\right)}{\rm d}x\\\\
&=8 \int_{0}^{\sqrt[8]{P(r)}} \,\frac{x^3}{x^4+0.0019x^2+0.002x+0.003}{\rm d}x\\
\end{align}
$$ and then conclude by a partial fraction decomposition of the form:
$$
\frac{x^3}{x^4+0.0019x^2+0.002x+0.003}=\frac{a_0 x+b_0}{x^2+\alpha_0x+\beta_0}+\frac{a_1 x+b_1}{x^2+\alpha_1x+\beta_1}.
$$

Comment: thank you , can you please clarify which one is a_0 and a_1 here?

Comment: @TazkeraHaqueTrina You may obtain, with the Mathematica command **'Apart[ ]'**, the decomposition:$$ \frac{-0.0880337+0.514102 x}{0.0579024-0.32835 x+x^2}+\frac{0.078773+0.485898 x}{0.0518113+0.32835 x+x^2}$$